# Spring reactive WebSocketHandler mono does not reach doFinally block

Tags: spring, kotlin, websocket, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to handle closing web socket session in `WebSocketHandler`. My intuition was to do it in this way:

```
webSocketClient.execute(
    URI.create("some-ws-endpoint")
) { session: WebSocketSession ->
    session.receive()
        .doOnEach { action(it) }
        .then()
        .doFinally { session.close() }
}
```

but I cannot reach `doFinally` block from `Mono<Void>` returned by `webSocketClient.execute`. My full test code for this case is:

```
fun test() = runBlocking {
        val webSocketClient: WebSocketClient = StandardWebSocketClient()

        val subscription = webSocketClient.execute(
            URI.create("some-ws-endpoint")
        ) { session: WebSocketSession ->
            session.receive()
                .doOnEach { println("Message: $it") }
                .then()
                .doFinally { println("finally") }
        }.subscribe()
    
        delay(20000)

        subscription.dispose()

        delay(5000)
    }
```

from which I have *Message*s printed, but *finally* is never shown on my console. From the other hand when I tried to do it on plain `reactor-core` components, everything works just fine:

```
runBlocking {
    val publisher: Flux<Long> = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    
    val subscription = publisher
        .doOnEach { println("Value: $it") }
        .then()
        .doFinally { println("in doFinally") }
        .subscribe()

    delay(5_000)

    subscription.dispose()

    delay(1_000)
}
```

I am new to both WebSockets and Project Reactor, so maybe I am doing some basic mistake. Does anyone see what is wrong with my code?

Comment: `doFinally` is only run after something terminates or is cancelled (according to the api docs) so one of the previous operators needs to send a cancellation or terminate signal. In you first example `then` does not send such signal or any of the other operators for that matter. Your second example has a `Flux` with a defined set, so when the `Flux` is ”finished” it sends a termination signal that triggers the `doFinally` block.

Comment: A websocket is a `Producer` and will most likely send a termination signal after you call `session.close()`

Comment: Well, from my understanding `Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))` creates endless `Flux` which emits value every second. When I didn't dispose subscription in the code then  "in doFinally" is not printed out. Also, inside `WebSocketHandler` functional interface, if I subscribed and disposed mentioned chain I had the same behaviour as in plain reactor example.